# How to open Facebook, Twitter, or email for share message or photo without using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have custom buttons and when a button is clicked, it should open the Facebook, Twitter, or email for sharing a message or photo.  It's just like to open the UIActivityViewController and click the Facebook, Twitter, or email.  How I can do that without using UIActivityViewController.  Thanks.

Comment: why dont you try to do it by yourself ? write code for sharing on facebook, twitter and email. why dont you want to use UIActivityViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook ([here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share))

Twitter ([here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios))

Email ([here](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-send-email-iphone-app/))

If you really need to share all 3 separately follow this links above. If you're a starter and have a limited time making your app,  I suggest you use `UIActivityViewController`, just create a **share** button that opens `UIActivityViewController`

Answer (score -1):

For Facebook message posting go here: http://www.geekylemon.com/xcode-facebook-posting

For Facebook image posting go here: http://www.geekylemon.com/xcode-facebook-image-posting

For Twitter posting go here: http://www.geekylemon.com/xcode-twitter

For Email go here: http://www.geekylemon.com/WEBPROTECT-xcodeinappemail.htm